# C# Telegram.Bot , OnMessage canceltoken not working

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, cancellation-token

I made a bot (Telegram.Bot version 19) that has the following structure:

```
TelegramBotClient bot = new Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient(textBox1.Text, httpClient);
start_bot();

        public async Task start_bot()
        {
            var token = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var canceltoken = token.Token;
            var option = new Telegram.Bot.Polling.ReceiverOptions { AllowedUpdates = { } };
            await bot.ReceiveAsync(OnMessage, OnError, option, canceltoken);
        }
        public async Task OnMessage(ITelegramBotClient bot_, Update update, CancellationToken canceltoken)
        {...}

        public async Task OnError(ITelegramBotClient bot_, Exception e, CancellationToken canceltoken)
        {...}
```

When an error occurs in **OnMessage**, the program no longer follows new messages, in fact, the update is no longer refreshed. (Of course, the program continues to work without any errors: it does nothing :))

When I close and open the bot, again the message is processed in which an error occurred.

I think the problem is in the CancellationToken !!

Is it possible to make **ReceiveAsync** send the next message to **OnMessage** with the try and catch block [ in **OnMessage** ]?

```
public async Task OnMessage(ITelegramBotClient bot_, Update update, CancellationToken canceltoken)
try
 {.... error ....}
catch
 {
   return new Task(؟؟؟);
 }
```